# PHP Zend Framework Zend_Pdf - number of pages of pdf document

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

simple thing which I need to do is, that I have a pdf document and i need return number of pages of this document. I should to do this with a Zend Framework.

Thanks in advance for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of pages by counting the elements of the [`$pages`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.pages.html) property:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf; // load your PDF file here
$pageCount = count($pdf->pages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count($pdf->pages)` to get the number of pdf pages.